# Find Most Recent File in a Directory That Matches Certain File Size

Tags: linux, find, ls

I need to find the most recently modified file in a directory that matches 3.0 MB.

**First Attempt**

```
ls -t /home/weather/some.cool*.file | head -n +1 | grep "3.0M"
```

**Second Attempt**

```
find /home/weather/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "some.cool*.file" -size 3M -exec ls -t "{}" +; | head -n +1
```

Am I close?

Comment: did you try `ls -lh --sort=time | grep "3.0M"` ?

Comment: This worked great after I added `| head -n =1` to the end. Please submit this comment as an answer.

Comment: Be sure to check out the `man` pages, lots of good information can be found there. `man ls` for the manual page for `ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`ls -lh --sort=time /path/to/directory/*.file | grep "3.0M" | head -n =1`

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is of some use -

`ls -ltr --block-size=MB | grep 3MB`

The latest modified files will be displayed at the bottom of the output.

The `-r` flag shows the output in reverse order and the `--block-size=MB` will show the size of files in MB.